# Why my role on aws is not correctly assumed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

On AWS I created a role on main account via terraform "My-role-ReadOnly" I am trying to assume this role from another account but if I am checking now command "aws sts get-caller-identity" , it is not correctly assumed, I assume that should be other identity? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "My-role-ReadOnly" {
  name = "My-role-ReadOnly"

   assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my_not_main_account_id>:root"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Condition": {}
   }
  ]
  }
  EOF
  }

   data "aws_iam_policy" "ReadOnlyAccess" {
   arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
  }

  resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  name       = "test-attachment"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.My-role-ReadOnly.name]
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.ReadOnlyAccess.arn
  }


 H:\tf>aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<main-account-id>:role/My-role-ReadOnly" --role- 
 session-name AWSCLI-Session
 {
"AssumedRoleUser": {
    "AssumedRoleId": "ARO:AWSCLI-Session",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<main-account-id>:assumed-role/My-role-ReadOnly/AWSCLI-Session"
},
"Credentials": {
    "SecretAccessKey": "/rV380jxxxxx",
    "SessionToken": "FwoGZXxxxxx",
    "Expiration": "2021-02-01T12:34:28Z",
    "AccessKeyId": "ASxxxxxx"
}
}

H:\tf>aws sts get-caller-identity
{
"Account": "<my_not_main_account_id>",
"UserId": "AIxxxxxxxx",
"Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<my_not_main_account_id>:user/terraform_user"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`aws sts assume-role` *return*s temporary credentials for the new role, it does not change the current environment, it does not change who / what you are currently logged in as.
You need to export the retrieved credentials into the environment. You can e.g. do that using `jq`:

```
credentials=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$provider_arn" --role-session-name "$provider_session_name" | jq ".Credentials")
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $credentials | jq -r ".AccessKeyId")
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $credentials | jq -r ".SecretAccessKey")
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $credentials | jq -r ".SessionToken")
```

*(the syntax for this depends on your OS / shell)* E.g. if you are on Windows use `set` instead of `export`.

Only after the credentials are exported will `aws sts get-caller-identity` return the new identity.

Comment: @acct_mik Code in comments needs to be wrapped in ` on both sides.

Comment: Yes I did this one what you mentioned and it didn't change anything, I have checked again aws sts get-caller-identity and there is the same result, I don't have an idea why?
 `C:\> setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ASIxxxx 
  C:\> setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY RtQxxxxxx 
  C:\> setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION eu-west-1
 `

Comment: @acct_mik the session token is important as well.

Comment: Yes sure, I will check with token one more time.

Comment: I have checked again but nothing change in below result, the same identity what before I assumed role

`H:\tf>aws sts get-caller-identity
{
"Account": "<my_not_main_account_id>",
"UserId": "AIxxxxxxxx",
"Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<my_not_main_account_id>:user/terraform_user"
}
`

Comment: I have the same issue with @acct_mik

Comment: @dugong I guarantee you that this works assuming you correct modify the environment variables afterwards. In particular `setx` seem to be the wrong tool for the job: https://superuser.com/q/916649/464605 - `set` should do the trick.

Comment: @acct_mik I am assuming you figured this out by now as well: `set` instead of `setx`.

Comment: I set them like this but my requests afterwards are not assumed `set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo ${AWS_STS_RESPONSE} | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
        set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo ${AWS_STS_RESPONSE} | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
        set AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo ${AWS_STS_RESPONSE} | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')`

Comment: @dugong not sure how you got `AWS_STS_RESPONSE` exactly - you may want to post a question about it, showing all the relevant commands in your situation. There is something you are doing wrong. Because I use this snippet tens of times each day and can absolutely 100% guarantee that it works every time, it does not ever not work.

Comment: This is it `AWS_STS_RESPONSE=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${AWS_ROLE}" --role-session-name aws-cli-session)`

Comment: I believe you, it should work, but it doesn't for me

Comment: That means, there is something wrong that can intervene which is not explained in here. I will post it if I discover what it is.

Comment: @dugong *maybe* you have to specify the `--output json` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html if you have a different default set in your cli config.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script, I see the variables being set properly

Comment: @dugong is this a separate script or do you just run these steps manually in the shell you are currently in? If you have it inside a script: do you run the `get-caller-identity` in that script as well? Can you run the identity cal with the environment variables directly like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... AWS_SECRET...=... aws sts get-caller-identity` without actually manually trying to export the values.

Comment: It is in a bash function defined in the current terminal session, I run the function, then I do the get-caller-identity. I will try what you said, that makes sense. Maybe my variables are being left behind in the subshell? I don't know yet, will let you know. Thanks!